# Use of "Just In Case"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, idioms

I was writing to someone and I had below line using "just in case"

*"I have done blah blah blah..., **just in case they need to be** so and so..."*

I was wondering if this the right way of using it?

or should it be

*"I have done blah blah blah..., **just in case if they needs to be** so and so..."*

Please suggest!!

Comment: There's a dated/archaic form *if/lest/in case it **needs be** [blah blah]*, where ***to*** never occurs. But you obviously don't want that - in your case it's definitely *in case they need to be [blah blah]* (the word ***just*** is entirely optional, and doesn't meaningfully add anything to the utterance).

Comment: ‘If’ basically means the same as ‘in case’ here, so having them both there is like saying, “Just if if they need…” or “Just in case in case they need…”.

Comment: The second one should be either "... they need ..." or "... there needs ..." but not "... they needs ....".

Comment: I think the second form (with the superfluos "if") is used often in speech, if not correctly, to imply that the conditional is even more unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "just in case" or simply "in case" has an implied meaning of "in [the] case [that]", which is why it can be followed up by "they need to be so and so". Adding the "if" turns the phrase to "just in [the] case [that] if they need to be so and so", which isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

Your original usage is, in my opinion, the correct usage of the term presented and I think your should keep it at that and not use the second option.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the phrase "just in case..." is short for "just in the case that...", as expanded below:

> "I have done blah blah blah..., **just in [the] case [that] they need to be** so and so..."